# Good addon's for Debugging Javascript against various browsers

Tags: javascript, debugging, cross-browser

Am using below tools to debug JavaScript in various browsers. Is there a common tool that can be used against all browsers for debugging JavaScript or suggest if there is any other better tools other than the one I provided for each browser.

- Firefox - Firebug add-on.(I like using this compared to other built in tools available for each browser).
- Chrome - Built-in console.
- Safari - Built-in console.
- IE - Developer tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) ? Its crossbrowser (IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome)

For Opera some people use [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for Firefox 
Chrome Developers tools for Chrome
Microsoft Script Debugger for IE